# WPF: Set MainWindow in App.xaml.cs, access it's variables

Tags: c#, wpf

in the past I could access a windows variables as it closes, so like a return parameter. But at the moment having an issue with this. See the code below:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        //Public list of users and form can access
        ObservableCollection<User> LoggedUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        public ObservableCollection<User> Logged
        {
            get
            {
                return LoggedUsers;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!AreSettingsSet())
            {
                this.MainWindow = new Views.LoginWindow();
                this.MainWindow.ShowDialog(); // Waits until closed.

                //If the login form was closed properly, handle the user
                if (MainWindow.DialogResult == true)
                {
                    //Add the user to the list of logged users
                    User returned = MainWindow.returnUser;
                    LoggedUsers.Add(returned);
                }

                // Recheck the settings now that the login screen has been closed.
                if (!AreSettingsSet())
                {
                    // Tell the user there is a problem and quit.
                    this.Shutdown();
                }
            }

            this.MainWindow = new Views.Main();
            this.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        private bool AreSettingsSet()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Logged.Count().ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code should open the login window if the `AreSettingsSet` method returns false (does at the moment for testing). This works fine, i'm having an issue with getting an object back from the `Views.LoginWindow()` window, here the code:

```
//Give App access to user object outside of this form
        public User returnUser
        {
            get
            {
                return user;
            }
        }

        //Public user object, start empty
        User user = new User();
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I get the `LoggedUsers` object from my login window? At the moment i'm getting an error on the following line.

Code:

```
User returned = MainWindow.returnUser;
```

Error:

> 'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'returnUser'
>   and no extension method 'returnUser' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework stores your **LoginWindow** as **Window**.

You can cast the **MainWindow** to **LoginWindow**

```
User returned = ((Views.LoginWindow)MainWindow).returnUser;
```

Or use the **as** operator

```
User returned = (MainWindow as Views.LoginWindow).returnUser;
```